# Request for tag hell-sing to be converted to hellsing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retagging

Can the tag "hell-sing" be renamed to "hellsing" please?

Comment: I tried to edit this, but the system gave me a strange error message that made me think that we'll need a mod to look at it. I flagged the question for mods, but we'll have to wait for some SE mods to show up to do this unless someone here knows how to get past that error message.

Comment: "Weird error":  "You are attempting to create the tag hellsing ; however the tag hell-sing already exists!"  Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I got the same error, hence posted in meta :)

Comment: If a tag is not used for any questions, it gets deleted automatically. So if it will not be fixed any soon, it's possible to temporarily retag that question to something else, wait for the old tag to be deleted, and then create a normal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is rather simple. Retag it to a different random tag, wait for it to be automatically deleted, and then retag it correctly.

I'm doing it right now and will report with the results.

EDIT: Done. Although a mod cheated :(