# Request to change xxx-holic tag to xxxholic

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

On the main site, the tag for xxxHolic is "xxx-holic". It should be changed to "xxxholic".

Comment: You should be able to just retag them manually.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Comment: If you have edit privileges, then mouse over the right of the tags and you'll see an "edit tags" button. Otherwise, just click the "retag" button.

Comment: Should I make this an answer?

Comment: I retagged one question, but that won't get rid of the xxx-holic tag, and I don't have edit privileges. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Tags with no questions are automatically purged after a few days.

Comment: I think your edit went into the suggested edit queue. Though you should be able to retag without going through that queue.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem with [hell-sing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hell-sing): [Request for tag hell-sing to be converted to hellsing](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210/request-for-tag-hell-sing-to-be-converted-to-hellsing). The solution is to remove [xxx-holic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xxx-holic) from all of the questions, wait a little bit until [xxx-holic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xxx-holic) is removed from the system, and then retag them all with [xxxholic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xxxholic). There's probably an easier way for moderators to do this, but we don't have pro temp mods yet.

For now, I've retagged all of the questions with [holic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holic). I've also saved the old tag wiki for [xxx-holic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xxx-holic). Once the system deletes [xxx-holic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xxx-holic) they can be retagged as [xxxholic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xxxholic) (I'll check back in a few hours if no one else fixes it before then), and I'll put the tag wiki back for the new tag.

Edit: I've replaced the interim tag with [xxxholic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xxxholic), so this should be resolved now. Tag wiki description will be back up once my edit gets peer reviewed.

Comment: Oh right I forgot that there's a tag collapsing mechanism to remove things like dashes and such. It's something you don't encounter often on a site like SO where all the tags are pretty much set.